# Prove the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}$ converges uniformly on any bounded interval of $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Prove the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}$ converges uniformly on any bounded interval of $\mathbb{R}$.
I was thinking about Weierstrass M-test but I got stuck.
Thank you so much for your time and help.

Comment: The series given is quite similar to Taylor expansion of $\sin(x).$

Comment: This is series of the $\sinh x$.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I$ be a bounded intervall. Then there is $c>0$ such that $|x| \le c$ for all $x \in I$. It follows that

$|\frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}| \le \frac{c^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}$ for all $x \in I$ and all $n$.

Since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{c^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}$ is convergent, the Weierstraß M - test shows that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}$  converges uniformly on $I$.

Comment: Hi Fred, I also did like that. But do we need to prove $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{c^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}$ converges by root test or ratio test? Or it is obvious, we do not need to prove it?

Comment: It is easy to see, by root test,that the series is convergent